# Set handset speaker as an output for audio player

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following function to play a sound if some condition == true, as this happens while the user is in call. Expected is that the sound should be played in the headset speaker, but if while in the call one put the call in handsfree / speaker, the sound is played on the other speaker where all audios are played. What I want is to define exactly where (on the headset) the audio file should be played. I was able to find only options for specifying the speaker as an output.

Here is the function:

```
//play a sound
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: alarmType, withExtension: ext) else { return }

    do {
        //try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .voiceChat)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        //here change the output to be on the handset
        
        /* The following line is required for the player to work on iOS 11. Change the file type accordingly*/
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        /* iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) */

        guard let player = player else { return }

        
      

        player.play()
       isItPlayed = true
        

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be much more precise about what you mean here by "headset speaker" and "other speaker." Do you mean "handset" rather than "headset?" Is there a bluetooth device involved? (Or possibly a car audio system?) On an iPhone, the bottom speaker is called the "speaker" and the top speaker is called the "receiver." It sounds like you want the audio played through the receiver when the user has requested audio to play through the speaker. That's very strange. What experience are you trying to achieve?

Comment: let's say if value >= 5 , then play that sound using the "receiver" speaker. What happens is the sound is played on the bottom speaker

Comment: Have you included that commented-out line? (The one with `overrideOutputAudioPort`.) It explicitly requests the speaker. It's very strange that you've turned off the microphone, but enabled `.voiceChat.` Voice chat is specifically for `.playAndRecord`. Are you saying that even though the user has requested all audio be sent to the speaker, you want your audio to go to the receiver anyway (when you're almost certainly not holding it to their head?) I suspect that's not possible.